# VSTO AddIn Form Showing a Dictionary

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to display a dictionary on a form in an Outlook 2013 AddIn with VSTO in C#.

Actually I want to display two dictionaries, maybe a large dialog with 2 listbox or something to list the key value pairs, or two tabs each with a listbox or something to display one dict and one tab to display the other dict.

Anyone know the best way to accomplish this?   I've tried all the methods I found online and none seem to work.  I'm a bit stuck.  Anyone know a good way to take achieve this?  The dictionaries are created during the AddIn startup within the OutlookRibbon class.  I can make them accessible from the outside if need be by making public properties if needed or just make the variables public.

This isn't part of my question, but I want to eventually perform CRUD operations on the dictionaries.  If there is a better way to accomplish this than a form with buttons that will manually perform the operatins, I'm all ears.  I am not using a database, this is a small addin and I need these dicts to be stored somewhere local and small.  They have about 15-25 entries each so they are not big.

Any advice and short examples would be much appreciated and a huge help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to display a dictionary on a form in an Outlook 2013 AddIn with VSTO in C#.

I'd suggest using Outlook form regions in that case. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in MSDN for more information. It is up to you which controls to use on the form (depends on the business logic). .Net framework allows to use a lot of third party controls.

> They have about 15-25 entries each so they are not big.

If you don't plan to store a huge amount of entries you may consider storing them in JSON or XML files.